# 403 Forbidden in airflow DAG Triggering API

Tags: python, postman, airflow

When I am trying to call the API from POSTMAN in Airflow DAG, I am facing a 403 Forbidden error.
I have enabled the headers for basic authentication with the username and password in Postman. In the airflow.cfg file, I have enabled `auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth`. This error occurs when I attempt to work solely in Postman. When I copy the same URL and try it directly in the browser, I am able to access the link.
I'm having trouble with authorization now that I've enabled authentication.

I attempted to use the curl command but received the same forbidden error.

The airflow version is 1.10.

Comment: Navigate directly to the url link and see if it challenges you.  Try your user name and password.  If that works, then I would try to use a website to base64 encrypt username:password.

Comment: @scott boston  Able to login to the site using their username and password attached screenshot above. how to encrypt base64 username and password in airflow?

Answer (score 2):

The basic auth seems fine, it is base64 encoded already. 403 means you are authorized in the application but this specific action is forbidden. In airflow there are different roles admin/dag manager/operator and not all roles are allowed to do DAG operations. Can you specify the user role and operations you try to do? Have in mind that base64 auth string can be easily decoded to plain text and people can see your username and password.
In the picture you have shared the verb you are using is POST, opening the link in tbe browser is probably a GET operation which is different in terms of permissions required.

Comment: @ Alex Karam what permission required for get operations?

Comment: Some roles allow you to see(GET) but dont allow you to create. If you are admin, should be able to do anything. I am not aware of your current role. Also not sure 100% that this is the problem but according to the status code it looks like role related issue.

Comment: I log in as admin.

Comment: send the url you are posting to, the last part

Comment: According to their docs, you can POST to /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs so in the place of ManifestGenerator you have to put real DAG id. I think that is the problem. Normally the dag ids look like: "dag_id": "test_6dfce472

Comment: Awesome, happy to hear :)